# Angular filter second-level object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$scope.orders = [
    {
        id: 1,
        costumer_id: 1,
        product_id: 1,
        quantity: 2,
        costumer:
        {
            id: 1,
            name: John Doe,
            age: 47,
            state: Georgia,
            province: Atlanta
        }
    },
];
```

What I wanto to do is create 3 input to filter it either by the costumer's name, the constumer's state or the costumer's province. This is what I am doing:

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:search">
    <td class="text-muted">{{ order.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.costumer.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.costumer.state }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.costumer.province }}</td>
    <td>
        {{ order.product_id }}
        <span class="label label-info">{{ order.quantity }} unidades</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the inputs to filter:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="search.$" placeholder="search for everything">
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="search.costumer.name" placeholder="filter by name">
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="search.costumer.state" placeholder="filter by state">
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="search.costumer.province" placeholder="filter by province">
```

Only the first input filter works, the others dont! How do I do this kind of  filtering?!

Thanks!

Comment: http://onoffswitch.net/filter-deep-object-properties-angularjs/

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504779/angularjs-filter-nested-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504779/angularjs-filter-nested-object)

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing in IE, I think it might be because `$scope.orders` has a trailing comma at the end of the array.

I've created a Plunkr for this here: http://plnkr.co/edit/P1LVvgjsRUYu9Z8cHGpR?p=preview