# filter doesn't work properly with nested data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish can group my data by hiding and showing them using filter.

I added `filter: {tabs.tabId: currentTab}` in ng-repeat but it returned blank. When I removed this line the data appear, it means the filter caused some problem.

demo http://jsfiddle.net/8Ub6n/4/

Comment: Can you look @ this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504779/angularjs-filter-nested-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work with deep nested values.

I would recommend to make your own filter:

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in user">
   <li ng-repeat="relation in friend.relationship | RelationFilter:currentTab">{{relation.name}} ({{relation.points}}points)</li>
</ul>
```

[..]

```
app.filter("RelationFilter", function () {
    return function (input, currentTab) {
        var output = [];

        for (var i in input) {                
            if (input[i].tabs.length >= 1 
                && input[i].tabs[0].tabId == currentTab) {               
                output.push(input[i]);
            }
        }      
        return output;
    };
});
```

check  JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8Ub6n/11/