# Angular Js Filtering nested array in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I want to filter nested array using angularjs filter in controller.
following is my sample data

```
dummy=[
    {
        category:'TV',
        data:[
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones',
                path: 'some data1',
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-SD',
                path: 'some data2'
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-HD',
                path: 'some data3'
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-Trailer 1',
                path: "some data4"
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-Trailer 2',
                path: "some data5"
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-Trailer 3',
                path: "Ssome data6"
            },
            {
                title: 'The Vampire Diaries ',
                path: 'some data7'
            },
            {
                title: 'The Vampire Diaries -SD',
                path: 'some data8'
            },
            {
                title: 'The Vampire Diaries -HD',
                path: 'some data9'
            },
            {
                title: 'The Vampire Diaries -Trailer 1',
                path: 'some data10'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        category:'LIVE',
        data:[
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones - Live Show',
                path: 'some data11'
            },
            {
                title: 'The Vampire Diaries  - Live Show',
                path: 'some data11'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

for example i want to filter the data on title, so if i search "game of thrones" i want to get following data

```
    {
        category:'TV',
        data:[
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones',
                path: 'some data1',
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-SD',
                path: 'some data2'
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-HD',
                path: 'some data3'
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-Trailer 1',
                path: "some data4"
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-Trailer 2',
                path: "some data5"
            },
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones-Trailer 3',
                path: "Ssome data6"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        category:'LIVE',
        data:[
            {
                title: 'Game of Thrones - Live Show',
                path: 'some data11'
            }
        ]
    }
```

I think similar question has been asked here 
[Angularjs filter nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504779/angularjs-filter-nested-object)

and i tried to use the following code in my controller but it did not worked

```
var filterdData = $filter('filter')(content, {data: [{title: $scope.filterKey}]});
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use $filter? Can't you just use a custom filter function?

Comment: @tasseKATT : yes angular version one

Comment: One as in 1.0.0? That is really old.

Comment: @tasseKATT:  sorry man typo mistake. its v1.3.12

Comment: Did the code version work for you?

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me

```
var filterdData = $filter('filter')(content, {data: {title: $scope.filterKey}});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

**Fast answer**:

Your screen must be something like this:

```
<td filter="{'Object.InnerObject': 'text'}">{{row.Object.InnerObject}}</td>
```

On your controller:

Add this function to convert the filters of ngTable to a JSON object that the AngularJS Filter understand.

```
var treatJSON = function(malformedJson){

    var treatedFilters = {};

    var subObjects = [];

    var auxiliarObject;

    var objectName;
    var objectValue;

    var keys = Object.keys(malformedJson);

    for(var index = 0; index < keys.length; index++){
        auxiliarObject = null;

        subObjects = keys[index].split('.');

        // Go adding the layers from bottom to up
        for(var innerIndex = subObjects.length - 1; innerIndex >= 0 ; innerIndex--){

            // Recovery the name and the value of actual object
            objectName = subObjects[innerIndex];
            objectValue = auxiliarObject || malformedJson[keys[index]];

            // Add the objet to the treated filters or add it to the chain for the next object to use it
            if(innerIndex == 0){
                treatedFilters[objectName] = objectValue;
            } else {
                auxiliarObject = {};
                auxiliarObject[objectName] = objectValue;
            }
        }
    }

    return treatedFilters;
};
```

And change the getData function to use the function above:

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
    var filteredRecords = 
        params.filter() 
            ? $filter('filter')($scope.records, treatJSON(params.filter()))
            : $scope.records;

    $defer.resolve(filteredRecords.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    params.total(filteredRecords.length);
}
```

---

**More Detailed Answer**:

I had the same problem and resolved it creating a function to decompose the object passed by the view.

The problem was the object devolved by the ngTable.

When the ngTable finds a complex object on the filter attribute, it does not parse the object, returning a flat string.
Ex:

This complex filter

```
<td filter="{'Object.InnerObject': 'text'}" class="text-right">
```

will be returned as

```
{'Object.InnerObject': ""}
```

However the AngularJS filter needs a well formed complex object to filter the field.
Then the function just transforme the last example to this:

```
{
    'Object':
    {
        'InnerObject': ""
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.