# Filter ng-repeat by status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown with values in it. They're accessed through the `.value` property. I have an `ng-repeat` on a `div` that is repeating a lot of data. That data has statuses. When a user selects to filter by a status in the dropdown, I want to filter the `ng-repeat` by whatever `status` they chose and the `status` in the `ng-repeat`. Here's a better example of what I mean:

```
data-ng-repeat="stackoverflow in overflows| filter:stackoverflow.property.status===status.value"
```

In my case, I need to access `stackoverflow.property.status` and compare it to whatever status is in the drop down.

Comment: could you elaborate more..so that picture would be clear for us

Comment: @PankajParkar just edited it

Comment: As i can see you wanted filter inner property object then you should look into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504779/angularjs-filter-nested-object ,,you could solve this by creating custom filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the circumstances, it ended up just being easier to write my own function and filter by it. In this case, I have a function search that I pass to filter. Works great for me.

I followed an answer that I found on another question. You can view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/suCWn/

```
$scope.search = function (shop) {

    if ($scope.selectedCityId === undefined || $scope.selectedCityId.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    var found = false;
    angular.forEach(shop.locations, function (location) {          
        if (location.city_id === parseInt($scope.selectedCityId)) {
            found = true;
        }
    });

    return found;
};`
```

Here's the question: [Angularjs filter nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504779/angularjs-filter-nested-object)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like the following:

```
<span ng-repeat="stackoverflow in overflows | filter: { status : selectedStatus }"></span>
```

`selectedStatus` will be the value of `ng-model` on your dropdown.

Comment: Not working for me...my filter would look like this now: `data-ng-repeat="stackoverflow in overflows | filter: { stackoverflow.property.status : status.value }"`

Comment: Have you tried `{ property.status : status.value }` ?

Comment: In that case your only option is to write a function that loops through all stackoverflows and returns only the objects that match the value of `status`

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this

```
ng-repeat="stackoverflow in overflows | filter: { locations: [{ status: status.value }] }"
```

Comment: That's awesome except one thing...I have another property value inside of there. So it would be locations.locations.status. Can I do that?

Comment: @Tom could you try that first then we could go for the next thing,,