# nested ng-repeat filter by ng-filter with ng-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter a table with a select field.
The selecting value is a nested ng-repeat.
(Mission belongsToMany projects, and I have a mission list...
in each mission there is another ng-repeat to loop the projects of each mission.

Here is my filter select:

```
<select
  ng-model="filterProject"
  ng-options="project.name for project in relatedprojects">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

And here is my ng-repeat table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="mission in missions | filter: { project : { name : filterProject }} ">
                            <td>
                                <span ng-if="mission.from_date != mission.to_date">
                                    [[mission.from_date]] -
                                    [[mission.to_date]]
                                </span>
                                <span ng-if="mission.from_date == mission.to_date">
                                    [[mission.from_date]]
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span ng-repeat='project in mission.projects'>
                                    [[project.name]]
                                </span>
                            </td>
.
.
.
.
```

When I load the site there is nothing displayed..
without the filter everything is ok.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: could you post js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ng-repeat="mission in missions | filter: { projects : { name : filterProject.name }} "
```

Shared the idea from [here](http://googleweblight.com/http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504779/angularjs-filter-nested-object&ei=WV4vAVEW&lc=en-IN&geid=10&s=1&m=495&ts=1455622232&sig=ALL1Aj6MQmCOLWchAWe2WH7uo52FxyfwwQ)

Comment: no.. sry, the same result.. no table data, no filter functionality

Comment: If try this: mission in missions | filter: { projects : { name : filterProject }} without the [ and ] I got table data, but no filter functionality

Comment: This does it ... mission in missions | filter: { projects : { name : filterProject.name }}  ... you push me into the right direction. thanks. Can you update your answer, I will except.

Comment: Print {{filteredProject}} and share the complete json

Comment: update to -> name : filterProject.name  instead of name : filterProject